# re-render only one child with react-hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```js
const {useRef, useState} = React;

function List(){
  const renderCount = useRef(0);
  console.log('<List /> is rendered', ++renderCount.current);
  const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = useState(false);
  const toggle = () => setIsClicked(!isClicked)
  return (
    <div>
      <ButtonA onClick={toggle} isClicked={isClicked} />
      <ButtonB />
    </div>
  )
}

function ButtonA(props){
  const renderCount = useRef(0);
  console.log('<ButtonA /> is rendered', ++renderCount.current);

  return (<button onClick={props.onClick} className={`${props.isClicked ? 'true':'false'}`} >Button A</button>);
}

function ButtonB(){
  const renderCount = useRef(0);
  console.log('<ButtonB /> is rendered', ++renderCount.current);
  
  return (<button>Button B </button>);
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <List />, document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```css
button.true{
  background-color: red;
}

button.false{
  background-color: blue;
  
  }
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

It's a sample code.

When I clicked `<ButtonA />`, and I expected re-rendering `<List />` and `<Button A/>`, but `<ButtonB />` was also re-rendered.

I wanna block re-rendering `<ButtonB />` when I click `<ButtonA />`

How can I achieve it?

Comment: I think you can use React.PureComponent to avoid it. Good luck.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of `React.memo` to have the same functionality as `shouldComponentUpdate` for functional component

```js
const {useRef, useState} = React;

function List(){
  const renderCount = useRef(0);
  console.log('<List /> is rendered', ++renderCount.current);
  const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = useState(false);
  const toggle = () => setIsClicked(!isClicked)
  return (
    <div>
      <ButtonA onClick={toggle} isClicked={isClicked} />
      <ButtonB />
    </div>
  )
}

function ButtonA(props){
  const renderCount = useRef(0);
  console.log('<ButtonA /> is rendered', ++renderCount.current);

  return (<button onClick={props.onClick} className={`${props.isClicked ? 'true':'false'}`} >Button A</button>);
}

const ButtonB = React.memo(() => {
  const renderCount = useRef(0);
  console.log('<ButtonB /> is rendered', ++renderCount.current);
  
  return (<button>Button B </button>);
})


ReactDOM.render(
  <List />, document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```css
button.true{
  background-color: red;
}

button.false{
  background-color: blue;
  
  }
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Optimizing a functional component so that React can treat it as a pure component shouldn’t necessarily require that the component be converted to a class component.

If you are already familiar with the recompose package then you know that it provides a wide collection of higher-order components that makes it very useful when dealing with functional components.

The recompose package exports a {pure} higher-order component that tries to optimize a React component by preventing updates on the component unless a prop has changed, using shallowEqual() to test for changes.

Using the pure higher-order component, our functional component can be wrapped as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import { pure } from 'recompose';

function ButtonB() {
  const renderCount = useRef(0);
  console.log('<ButtonB /> is rendered', ++renderCount.current);

  return (<button>Button B </button>);
}
// Wrap component using the `pure` HOC from recompose
export default pure(ButtonB);
```

Answer (score 0):

By default all children of the parent is re-rendered if the parent's state changes. No matters if this change has a direct effect to the child or not.
However you can explicitly disable the re-render of a specific component using the [shouldComponentUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) lifecycle method.

```js
class Button extends React.Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate(){
    return !this.props.shouldNotUpdate;
  }
  
  render(){
    const { id, onClick } = this.props;
    console.log(`button ${this.props.id} rendered`)
    return <button onClick={onClick}>{`Button ${id}`}</button>
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { clicked: 0 }
  
  handleClick = () => this.setState(({clicked}) => ({clicked: clicked + 1}))
  
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.clicked}<br />
        <Button id="1" onClick={this.handleClick} />
        <Button id="2" shouldNotUpdate />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```